# Windows 10 - "Something went wrong" - Windows Store / account problems

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, windows-store, microsoft-account

**Scenario**

So recently I was trying to install something from the Windows 10 store. I clicked the Get button and it asks for me to verify my Microsoft account. I entered my email address in and password for the Microsoft account I had made before. It comes back with an error saying "Oops, something went wrong. Service unavailable" (no error code).

[image]

Followed by:

[image]

When I try again "later" the same thing appears. This has been going on for about a month so definitely something wrong on my end.

I tried to use another email address, creating a new Microsoft account from that and I get this "Something went wrong, please try again later 0x80190005". I tried to look up this error code but there is not much information out there from google.

**Problem**

The main problem is not being able to log in to the Microsoft Store. When I goto microsoft.com and log in to my account, it lets me log in without any issues.

**What I have tried**

- I have tried making a new account as stated under my scenario with a different email address. I have tried going to Internet Options > Advanced > turning on SSL3.0, TLS1.0, TLS1.1, TLS1.2 as suggested on several sites. SSL2.0 does not appear in my list even though suggested to enable but since not in my list, I can not turn it on of course.
- I have tried deleting the contents of the two folders:
  C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore and C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download as suggested as well. It deletes the contents of Download no problem but states that the files under the DataStore folder are in use.
- I have verified that Windows Firewall is indeed turned on.
- My time and date are accurate (some suggested this as well)
- My account I am logged in as is Admin, has a PIN and password set up on it (some suggested using a PIN to fix this)

So as you can see, I have tried everything I could find out there and I am still unable to download anything from the Microsoft Store.  Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Also let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution I found is to add a new admin to the computer using CMD (ran as administrator):

```
net user NAME /add
net localgroup administrators NAME /add
```

where NAME is the user name to add.

To maintain my original user's name, I created a temporary admin account, logged in, copied my old account files over, deleted the original, then repeated again to a new account with the original's name.  This has to be done since you can't rename account names in Windows 10.

To remove an account I did so through "Accounts" under Control Panels.

I then switched to the new admin user and everything worked fine.  This seems to be more of a work around but I could not find any other solution out there to work.